# Automatische Silbentrennung im Titel von Fragen

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Folgendes Beispiel zeigt, dass die automatische Silbentrennung gelegentlich fehlerhafte Ergebnisse produziert:

[image]

Ich vermute, dass in allen stack exchange communities die gleichen (wohl englischen) Trennungsregeln verwendet werden. Ist das einen "feature request" wert?

Comment: Oh, gute Beobachtung! Ich bin für einen Feature-Request. Aber es dürfte nicht so leicht sein, weil wir ja auch Fragen mit englischen Titeln hier haben - dort müsste die Trennung dann auf englisch sein. Und das bedeutet, dass die Seite erkennen müsste, in welcher Sprache ein Titel ist. Noch komplizierter wird es, wenn ein Titel englische und deutsche Anteile hat - etwa ein englischer Post mit deutschen Worten in Anführungszeichen. Aber vielleicht muss man sich mit einer 80-20-Lösung zufrieden geben.

Comment: Ich hab mal die letzten 5000 Titel gescrapt. Hast Du Lust, die Sprache darin (vielleicht erst mal nur in den ersten 500 oder 1000) zu klassifizieren? - hier wäre die Google-Tabelle: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mrpe9CadK_fK1eAcP9-OCjXzSRwtwBqWtNdTHxhlkis Wir könnten das als Basis heranziehen, um eine einfache Sprachklassifikation zu bewerten - entweder eine ML-basierte Klassifkation oder regelbasiert auf Basis einfacher Heuristiken. Ein erster Blick offenbart, dass die gemischtsprachige Titel ziemlich häufig sind.

Comment: Anscheinend gibt es bereits eine Anfrage, die Silbentrennung in Titeln ganz zu deaktivieren: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376198/hyphenation-in-titles-makes-it-difficult-to-read-quickly Das scheint mir auch für uns die einfachste Lösung zu sein :)

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ich mache mich an die Arbeit ...

Comment: Moment! Ich habe bereits 1000 Titel klassifiziert. Aber viel wichtiger: DIe beste Lösung ist wahrscheinlich, Silbentrennung im Titel ganz zu verbieten. Bis das nicht geklärt ist, solltest du dir die Arbeit nicht machen.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Okay! Keine Silbentrennung im Titel ist eine gute Lösung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da wir sowohl englische als auch deutsche als auch gemischtsprachige Titel haben, dürfte es schwer werden, eine orthografisch korrekte Silbentrennung zu implementieren.

Das einfachste scheint zu sein, die Silbentrennung im Titel ganz zu unterlassen.

Es gibt auf meta.stackexchange [eine Feature-Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/376201#376201), das eben erst neu eingeführte Feature der Trennung im Titel wieder abzuschaffen. Es scheint mir am aussichtsreichsten, diese Request mit einem Upvote zu unterstützen.